# Using cloud-init as custom_data with ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, yaml, cloud-init

I deploy a VM using an `ansible playbook`, similar to [this demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ansible-create-vm).

```
- name: Create VM
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: myResourceGroup
    name: myVM
    ...
    custom_data: cloud-init.yml
```

Now I also want to install some packages and do some minor preparations. I made a `cloud-config.yml`

```
#cloud-config

package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - npm
  - nodejs-legacy

runcmd:
- sudo mkdir -p /data/projects/
```

It seems that `cloud-init.yml` is not executed, so I guess this is not the correct syntax. How should you pass cloud-init files in an ansible playbook? Or is there another method to reach this goal?

Comment: Try `custom_data: "{{ lookup('file', 'cloud-init.yml') }}"`

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom_data` parameter in `azure_rm_virtualmachine` requires the data, not a filename.

You can use `file` lookup plugin to fetch the data from a file on an Ansible controller:

```
- name: Create VM
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: myResourceGroup
    name: myVM
    ...
    custom_data: "{{ lookup('file', 'cloud-init.yml') }}"
```